# Using sed script to generate an awk script

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm looking for a way to generate an awk file using sed. The problem at hand is, I have a text file with about 1000 rows of words and I want to be able to extract each line from the text file and use the word extracted as a regex in an awk file.

For example the text file will read:

```
James    Class1
Toby     Class3
Callum   Class4
Sarah    Class1
Jeremiah Class2
```

Output to awk using sed should look like

```
/ reg exp for James/ {action matching word has Class1}
/ reg exp for Toby / {action matching word has Class3}
/ reg exp for Callum / {action matching word has Class4}
/ reg exp for Sarah / {action matching word has Class1}
```

I've tried extracting all the words using sed but can't seem to find a way to write that to an awk file!

Comment: Welcome to SO, not clear, why do you need a `sed` for creating an `awk` program? Please be more clear with more details in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Also please confirm do you really want to print text `action matching word has Class1` etc or you want it actual code some conditions to be printed in a script or etc which you want to execute it later?

Comment: thanks for your help Ravinder, basically the task is to create a sed file that generates many lines of awk code that count the number of students in a certains. the end output should be able to count how many students in class1, class2 and class3.

Comment: So you need to count how many students named `James` are in `Class1`, `Class2` etc? That can be done much better than this.

Comment: @PesaThe correct, but I also need to count the number of students in a class. needs to be done using sed though.

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: @DavidE, if you could share the sample input and sample expected output I believe this could be done in single `awk` itself, please do share the same in your post.

Comment: @DavidE, I have voted for closing this question as of now, once you update proper details with your efforts which you put in order to solve this, I will retract this vote then.

Comment: `I'm looking for a way to generate an awk file using sed.` - that makes zero sense. If you can parse the input file with sed then you can certainly parse it with awk and if you can produce an awk script to do something from sed then you can just write the awk script to do whatever that something is. Tell your teacher to come up with a more useful/realistic exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [`GNU awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) (works only in  [`GNU awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) due to the multi dimensional array syntax, as noted by [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)):

```
awk '{ a[$2][$1]++ }
END {
    for(i in a) {
        sum=0
        printf "=== %s ===\n", i
        for(j in a[i]) {
            sum+=a[i][j]
            printf "%s: %d\n", j, a[i][j]
        }
        printf "> %d\n", sum
    }  
}' data
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat data
Sarah    Class1
James    Class2
Sarah    Class1
Sarah    Class2
Peter    Class1
$ ./script
=== Class1 ===
Sarah: 2
Peter: 1
> 3
=== Class2 ===
James: 1
Sarah: 1
> 2
```

Comment: @EdMorton Good point, will edit it into my answer. Any other suggestions are welcome :)